# How to printf values from a structure in an external function to main()

Tags: c, struct

In the below code I am creating my own `div()` function to start understanding structures. The only thing that I am missing is how to `printf()` the values in the external function I created: `division_function`. Could you let me know how to get that right? Thank you very much guys!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int quotient;
    int remainder;
} division;

void division_function(int dividend, int divisor, division *own_divresult);

int main(void)
{

    int dividend = 0, divisor = 0;

    puts("Please enter two integers:");
    scanf("%d%d", &dividend, &divisor);

    division own_divresult;
    division_function(dividend, divisor, &own_divresult);

    return 0;
}

/* Own division function */
void division_function(int dividend, int divisor, division *own_divresult)
{
    own_divresult -> quotient = dividend / divisor;
    own_divresult -> remainder = dividend % divisor;
    printf ("%d div %d => %d, remainder %d.\n", dividend, divisor, 
        own_divresult.quotient, own_divresult.remainder);
}
```

Comment: `own_divresult.quotient, own_divresult.remainder` - > `own_divresult->quotient, own_divresult->remainder`

Comment: No problem……...

Comment: Always a bug: not testing the return value from scanf(). With `"%d%d"` where does the first integer end and the second begin?

Comment: Note: C library has `div_t`, much like `typedef struct 
{
    int quotient;
    int remainder;
} division;`

Comment: @Jens Please let me know what you mean by that? Thank you!

Comment: @Henry I was expecting a blank between the two %d, but it works without. However, you always should test if scanf returns 2 (for two converted ints), otherwise you have garbage data.

Comment: thank you @Jens for further explaining. I have added the space in my answer below. However, I still don't know how to check if the user has entered two integers by just looking at what `scanf` returns. Afaik if a user entered, for instance, a `3` and a `z`, `scanf` would still return `2` if data type used in `scanf` is `%d`. How would you go about this? Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Henry No, when scannig "3 z" with "%d %d" it returns 1, because scanf returns the number of successful conversions. "z" cannot be converted to an int.

Comment: @Jens I was getting something different, but that was my code being wrong. Thank you again for all your help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving the final answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int quotient;
    int remainder;

} division;

void division_function(int dividend, int divisor, division *own_divresult);

int main()
{

int dividend = 0, divisor = 0;

puts("Por favor introduzca dos números enteros:");
scanf("%d %d", &dividend, &divisor);

division own_divresult;
division_function(dividend, divisor, &own_divresult);

return 0;

}

/* Función propia de división */
void division_function(int dividend, int divisor, division *own_divresult)
{
    own_divresult->quotient = dividend / divisor;
    own_divresult->remainder = dividend % divisor;
    printf ("%d div %d => %d, remainder %d.\n", dividend, divisor, own_divresult->quotient, own_divresult->remainder);
}
```